# Is this picture of the electron dipole moment correct?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, dipole

[image]

It's the electron spinning on its axis, and a magnetic moment shoots up. The direction of the North-South is opposite what I thought it should be. Why is the vector arrow pointing from North to South and not opposite that? Shouldn't the magnetic moment arrow be pointing down?

Comment: This may help: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/10030/520

Comment: See [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/63831/8563) for the orientation of the north and south magnetic poles for a loop of current.